# converting a CSV to a shapefile in python

Tags: python

I managed to extract from a json file some data into a csv file. it goes like this:

```
,data,lat,lon
2001-05-05 14:00:00+00:00,373.93,-155.5763,19.5362
2001-05-12 14:00:00+00:00,373.44,-155.5763,19.5362
2001-05-19 14:00:00+00:00,373.92,-155.5763,19.5362
...
```

and now I would like to convert them into a shapefile using python only. 
 And I'm not getting anywhere close to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Check the below URL:
They are using pyshp module. 
https://glenbambrick.com/2016/01/09/csv-to-shapefile-with-pyshp/